Connect to disregarded host through VPN
m looking for some help, I'm trying to connect to a host under a 4G router through VPN.
First step, I'm using a raspberry pi 5 with raspberry pi os 64 bits, with openvpn3 installed on it. On a Synology NAS I have activated the OpenVPN server and opened the firewall ports to work with it.
Everything is working, from any computer I can connect with OpenVPN Connect to the VPN and the raspberry is also connected to the VPN server, so I can reach the raspberry.
IP Configuration:

Raspberry: local IP 192.168.5.100, VPN IP 10.8.0.5
PC: local IP 192.168.1.105, VPN IP 10.8.0.6

Now the problem: in the same net as the raspberry, I have a device (192.168.5.14) accessible via http, and I want to reach it from the pc connected to the vpn.
I have investigated how could I configure the raspberry to create any static route, or create some type of redirection to a "imaginary ip", for example 10.8.0.20, that points to the device. Also I configure to point raspberry 80 port to device's 80 port.
Someone can help me to configure this?

Can you draw a diagram of how the things are connected?

@grawity so easy to understand, because cgnat limitations with 4g, the device I want to access remotely has in its net a raspberry with openvpn client, connecting to openvpn server in another net. Connecting with a laptop from anywhere to the vpn, I can reach the raspberry (ssh, vnc) but what I want, is to access directly my device via http (like doing vnc to raspberry and inside it, writing device's ip in the browser) but without doing vnc, because 4g is limitated and remote control uses a lot mobile data.
